# Android Image Rectangle Detection with NO OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, renderscript, vision, cidetector

I'm baffled that on Android we have to import a 30 MB OpenCV library to detect rectangles in images / video frames. On iOS that is pretty easy using CIDetector.

Has anyone found a solution that isn't OpenCV based? Maybe using Renderscript? I've found [this](https://gist.github.com/ZacSweers/aac5f2e684e125e64ae6b1ad0a2540aa) one (explained [here](https://www.zacsweers.dev/detecting-blurriness-with-renderscript/)) which implements some kind of edge detection, but I'm not sure whether this is the right basis to extend. Any vision / graphics expert out there who could evaluate this and maybe point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hey Harry did you find a solution to this ? I have had a bit of trouble as well finding a clear solution without the use of OpenCV.

Comment: Unfortunately not. :/